# Is there a way of measuring the spin along an arbitrary direction of a spin 1 particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I am familiar with the expression for spin 1/2 but haven't seen one for spin 1.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean exactly? What is the expression you're familiar with for spin 1/2?

Comment: Using the same method as this http://www.uvm.edu/~kspartal/EPR_Simulation/AboutSpins.pdf which is for the spin 1/2 particle and apply it to the spin 1 particle

Comment: If you plug the spin-1 representation for $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$ (which I posted below) into the very first equation of this pdf (i.e. into the definition of $S_r$) you can go through the steps of this document and obtain the respective expressions for spin-1. The difference being, that you are now dealing with $3\times 3$-matrices instead.

Comment: Already done it. The problem just came when normalising my eigenvectors using the mathematica function I had some degeneracies but calculating it by hand sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm getting your question correctly, but the general spin operator is given by
 \begin{equation}
    \widehat{S} = a\cdot \widehat{S}_x + b\cdot \widehat{S}_y + c\cdot \widehat{S}_z
 \end{equation}
 where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\vec{n} \equiv (a\; b\; c)$ is the direction in which you measure the spin. Note that so far, no particular spin (1/2, 1, 3/2 etc.) has been specified. As you will probably know, the operators $\widehat{S}_x, \widehat{S}_y$ and $\widehat{S}_z$ are required to satisfy a very specific algebraic relation, namely
 \begin{equation}
   [\widehat{S}_\alpha, \widehat{S}_\beta] = i\hbar\ \varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}^{~~~~~\gamma}\ \widehat{S}_\gamma \qquad \forall\, \alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \{x,y,z\}\ .
 \end{equation}
Now, to put it in "simple words", you go looking for matrices that satisfy this relation (i.e. representations of the algebra). If you look for $2\times 2$-matrices you may find that
\begin{equation}
 \widehat{S}_x \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\
 \widehat{S}_y \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix},\
 \widehat{S}_z \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\
\end{equation}
will do the trick (recognize the Pauli matrices). This representation by $2\times 2$ matrices is called a spin-1/2 representation. Now, you may go on and look for a representation by $3\times 3$ matrices and find
\begin{equation}
 \widehat{S}_x \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\, ,\
 \widehat{S}_y \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i & 0 \\ i & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{pmatrix}\, ,\
 \widehat{S}_z \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \hbar\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\ .
\end{equation}
This is a spin-1 representation. Note that conventionally the basis is chosen in such a way that $\widehat{S}_z$ is a diagonal matrix and the entries on its main diagonal correspond to the possible outcomes of your measurements, i.e. ($+\frac{\hbar}{2}$, $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$) for the spin-1/2 case and ($+\hbar$, $0$, $-\hbar$) for the spin-1 case.

Comment: This is fine for non-elementary particles, as well as for atoms with angular momentum $L$, but beware of photons, which don't have a rest frame, and therefore only helicity.

Comment: That is absolutely true. As I said, I'm not sure if I'm getting the question correctly.

Comment: My best interpretation of the question is the literal one, so I would say a [Stern-Gerlach apparatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment), heh